# JSON to CSV (getting only first row from the JSON file)

Tags: r, json, csv, rjson

I have a JSON file. I would like to convert this JSON file into CSV. I have gone through several posts in the Stack Overflow and R Studio Community. After reading them, I wrote a code.

My code is working only for the first row. This means, I am getting only 1st row from the JSON file. But, my JSON file containing 1024 rows. I check the file through the online website and received 1024 rows.

```
Compound <- fromJSON(file = "~/Compound.json")
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(Compound,c)))
```

Could you tell me, why I am getting only 1 row or how can I solve these issues?

Comment: Please share example data so we can reproduce your error.

Comment: If your file has one complete JSON object per line/row, then it is technically "ndjson" (newline-delimited json), which is parsed correctly by `jsonlite::stream_in`.

Comment: @r2evans thanks. Maybe this is the problem. Could you tell me how can I solve the problem?

Comment: *I did.* If your data is truly ndjson, replace your call to `fromJSON` with `stream_in`. If your data is not ndjson, then it won't work. I don't really know, though, since I don't know what's in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using `jsonlite` lite package. Because, my JASON was `"ndjson" (newline-delimited json)`. Received help from a post comment by `r2evans`

```
install.packages("jsonlite")
library(jsonlite)

json <- stream_in(file("~/Food.json"), simplifyDataFrame=FALSE)
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(json,c)))
```